# How to use aggregate to group mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to populate my user document with his talents and talent media. But I'm getting repeated objects. I want to get talent as an object and the medias against that talent inside an array.

my user model:

```
{
    _id: '5f1acd6e6985114f2c1567ea',
    name: 'test user',
    email: 'test@email.com'
}
```

talent model

```
{
    _id: '5f1acd6e6985114f2c1567fa',
    categoryId: '5f1acd6e6985114f2c1567ga',
    userId: '5f1acd6e6985114f2c1567ea'
    level: '5',
}
```

talent-media model

```
{
    _id: 5f1acd6e6985114f2c156710',
    talentId: '5f1acd6e6985114f2c1567fa',
    media: 'file.jpg',
    fileType: 'image'
}
```

I have another model for storing the category

```
{
    _id: '5f1acd6e6985114f2c1567ga',
    title: 'java'
}
```

I want the result as follows

```
user: {
  _id: '',
  name: 'test user',
  email: 'test@email.com',
  talents: [
    {
      _id: '',
      level: '5',
      categoryId: {
        _id: '',
        title: 'java'
      },
      medias: [
        {
           _id: '',
           file: 'file1.jpg',
           fileType: 'image'
        },
        {
           _id: '',
           file: 'file2.jpg',
           fileType: 'image'
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I also tried adding talent-medias embedded in talent documents. But in MongoDB document found is not mostly recommended.
Is it better to have talent model like this,

```
{
    _id: '5f1acd6e6985114f2c1567fa',
    categoryId: '5f1acd6e6985114f2c1567ga',
    userId: '5f1acd6e6985114f2c1567ea'
    level: '5',
    medias: [
        {
           _id: '',
           file: 'file1.jpg',
           fileType: 'image'
        },
        {
           _id: '',
           file: 'file2.jpg',
           fileType: 'image'
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) multiple times:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "talents",
      let: {
        userId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$userId",
                "$userId"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "categories",
            let: {
              categoryId: "$categoryId"
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$categoryId",
                      "$_id"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                $project: {
                  _id: "",
                  title: 1
                }
              }
            ],
            as: "categoryId"
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "talent_media",
            let: {
              talentId: "$_id"
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$talentId",
                      "$talentId"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                $project: {
                  _id: "",
                  file: "$media",
                  fileType: "$fileType"
                }
              }
            ],
            as: "medias"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: "$categoryId",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: "",
            categoryId: 1,
            level: 1,
            medias: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "talents"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "",
      email: 1,
      name: 1,
      talents: 1
    }
  }
])
```

*You'll probably have to adapt the collection names.

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B19AzzAgm91)

Comment: Thank you @Tom Slabbaert

Comment: For single user s an Object how to get the result?

Comment: Please do consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63489700/flter-mongodb-database-using-mongoose-nodejs/63490444#63490444

Answer (score 0):

You have to use nested [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/),

- lookup with <kbd>Talent Collection</kbd> and match `userId`
- $match for specific user _id document, commented here

```
db.User.aggregate([
  /** add here
  Optional for single user
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
  },
  */
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Talent",
      as: "talents",
      let: {
        userId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$userId",
                "$userId"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
```

- we are now inside Talent Document and lookup with <kbd>Category Collection</kbd> and match with `categoryId`
- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) category because it will return array and we need object

```
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "Category",
            as: "categoryId",
            localField: "categoryId",
            foreignField: "_id"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: "$categoryId",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
          }
        },
```

- again we are inside Talent Document and lookup with <kbd>Talent Media Collection</kbd> and match with `talentId`
- `$project` for add/remove not needed fields, here removed `talentID` from TalentMedia nad removed `userId` from Talent

```
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "TalentMedia",
            as: "medias",
            let: {
              talentId: "$_id"
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$talentId",
                      "$talentId"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                $project: {
                  talentId: 0
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            userId: 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Separated query in parts for explanation, You can combine as they are in sequence.

Working Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/poIbvFUMvT4

Comment: Yes! you saved my day. How do this works for a single user by passing a user _id?

Comment: But I'm getting the result as an array. Not as a user object.

Comment: ok...can u give me a demo to get only the talents array populated with the media as an array inside the talent? Without the user details. like: `talents:[{ _id, level, category: {_id, title }, medias: [{ _id, file, fileType }, {_id, file, fileType} ] }]` this