# Flter mongodb database using mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to filter some users according to some fixed criteria. I have a **user** collection and a **talent** collection. The talent collection holds the reference to a master **category** collection.

What I need is to filter these users according to the **category** in the talent collection and some keys from the user collection.

`For example I need to search for a user whose gender is 'male' and education 'BTech' and will have talents as a programmer and tester`

my user collection is like,

```
{
    "_id": "5f1939239bd35429ac9cd78f",
    "isOtpVerified": "false",
    "role": "user",
    "adminApproved": 1,
    "status": 0,
    "languages": "Malayalam, Tamil, Telugu, Kannada",
    "name": "Test user",
    "email": "test@email.com",
    "phone": "1234567890",
    "otp": "480623",
    "uid": 100015,
    "bio": "Short description from user",
    "dob": "1951-09-07T00:00:00.000Z",
    "gender": "Male",
    "education": "Btech",
    "bodyType": "",
    "complexion": "",
    "height": "",
    "weight": "",
    "requests": [],
    "location": {
        "place": "place",
        "state": "state",
        "country": "country"
    },
    "image": {
        "avatar": "5f1939239bd35429ac9cd78f_avatar.jpeg",
        "fullsize": "5f1939239bd35429ac9cd78f_fullsize.png",
        "head_shot": "5f1939239bd35429ac9cd78f_head_shot.jpeg",
        "left_profile": "5f1939239bd35429ac9cd78f_left_profile.png",
        "right_profile": "5f1939239bd35429ac9cd78f_right_profile.png"
    },
    "__v": 42,
    "createdAt": "2020-07-23T07:15:47.387Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-08-18T18:54:22.272Z",
}
```

Talent collection

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f38efef179aca47a0089667",
        "userId": "5f1939239bd35429ac9cd78f",
        "level": "5",
        "chars": {
            "type": "Fresher",
        },
        "category": "5f19357b50bcf9158c6be572",
        "media": [],
        "createdAt": "2020-08-16T08:35:59.692Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-16T08:35:59.692Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f3b7e6f7e322948ace30a2c",
        "userId": "5f1939239bd35429ac9cd78f",
        "level": "3",
        "chars": {
            "type": "Fresher",
        },
        "category": "5f19359250bcf9158c6be573",
        "media": [
            {
                "adminApproved": 0,
                "status": 0,
                "_id": "5f3c22573065f84a48e04a14",
                "file": "id=5f1939239bd35429ac9cd78f&dir=test&img=5f1939239bd35429ac9cd78f_image_undefined.jpeg",
                "description": "test",
                "fileType": "image",
                "caption": "test file"
            },
            {
                "adminApproved": 0,
                "status": 0,
                "_id": "5f3c2d7a8c7f8336b0bfced2",
                "file": "id=5f1939239bd35429ac9cd78f&dir=test&img=5f1939239bd35429ac9cd78f_image_1.jpeg",
                "description": "this is a demo poster for testing",
                "fileType": "image",
                "caption": "A Test Poster"
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2020-08-18T07:08:31.532Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-18T19:35:22.899Z",
        "__v": 2
    }
]
```

And the category in the above document is a separate one populated to this. the category collection as,

```
[
        {
            "_id": "5f19359250bcf9158c6be573",
            "status": true,
            "title": "Testing",
            "description": "Application tester",
            "code": "test",
            "characteristics": [],
            "createdAt": "2020-07-23T07:00:34.221Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-07-23T07:00:34.221Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "status": true,
            "_id": "5f29829a705b4e648c28bc88",
            "title": "Designer",
            "description": "UI UX Designer",
            "code": "uiux",
            "createdAt": "2020-08-04T15:45:30.125Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-08-04T15:45:30.125Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f19357b50bcf9158c6be572",
            "status": true,
            "title": "programming",
            "description": "Java programmer",
            "code": "program",
            "createdAt": "2020-07-23T07:00:11.137Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-07-23T07:00:11.137Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
```

So my filter terms will be;

```
{
    categories: ["5f19359250bcf9158c6be573", "5f19357b50bcf9158c6be572"],
    minAge: 18,
    maxAge: 25,
    minHeight: 5,
    maxHeight: 6,
    minWeight: 50,
    maxWeight: 80,
    complexion: "white",
    gender: "male",
}
```

And the expected result will be a user have both the above talents and followed conditions,

```
{
    users: { ..User details.. },
    medias: { ...medias from the matching talents.. }
}
```

Comment: is this same question that you have asked? [Filter mongodb documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482189/filter-mongodb-documents)

Comment: Deleted that one. Needed some changes. Can you help me on this?

Comment: you can edit that question, and delete this question.

Comment: @turivishal Not able to get the result tried lookup and match. but seems wrong.

Comment: not getting exact question, can you describe properly, edit and put the things in your question 1) collection one documents 2) collection two documents 3)  expected result from that documents and 4) what you have tried so far.

Comment: @turivishal Please check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220102/discussion-between-lijomon-c-john-and-turivishal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [$lookup with pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries),

- `$match` you condition for `category` match
- `$lookup` to join `users` collection

  - `$match` conditions for users collections fields
- `$match` exclude documents that don't found matching `users` of criteria passed in conditions

```
db.talents.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      category: { $in: ["5f19359250bcf9158c6be573", "5f19357b50bcf9158c6be572"] }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      as: "users",
      let: { userId: "$userId" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$$userId", "$_id"] },
                { $eq: ["$gender", "Male"] },
                { $eq: ["$education", "Btech"] }
                // ... add you other match criteria here 
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $match: { users: { $ne: [] } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fyEFDy6t4bx)

Comment: This filters the data but the problem is in each talent a user is coming if the user have two talents the user is coming as twice in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If there are two `collections` you need to `join` them either by `primary key` or `_id`  with foriegn fields and you can use `$lookup` with `$match` to filter down.
[Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: To expand on this - you will need to use an Aggregation. There are a few ways to write this, but in general, the first step will be the `$lookup` mentioned, to join the documents from the two collections. Then a `$match` to filter down to your criteria.

Comment: Thanks Adam for adding. As $lookup with help aggregate then to filter you can use $match or can even use find.